# sed pattern matching not working

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to create a bash script to automate extracting tar archives and my sed regex is not acting as expected.  If I do:

```
archive=$1
directory=$(sed "s/.tar.bz2$//" <<< $archive)
echo "extracting $archive to $directory"
```

I get :

```
$ sh extract binutils-2.27.tar.bz2
extracting binutils-2.27.tar.bz2 to binutils-2.27
```

which is as expected.

But if I do :

```
archive=$1
directory=$(sed "s/.tar.[a-z0-9]{2,3}$//" <<< $archive)
echo "extracting $archive to $directory"
```

which is what I want to do (so as to handle any type of archive), I'd expect to get the same output, but I'm getting :

```
$ sh extract binutils-2.27.tar.bz2
extracting binutils-2.27.tar.bz2 to binutils-2.27.tar.bz2
```

As you can see the regex is not applying.

I've tested my regex on regex101.com and it seems to be correct, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly in the bash script.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to what is going wrong please.

I'm on Mint 17.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `-E` flag on `sed`:

```
$ archive=binutils-2.27.tar.bz2
$ directory=$( sed "s/.tar.[a-z0-9]{2,3}$//" <<< $archive)
$ echo $directory
binutils-2.27.tar.bz2
$ directory=$( sed -E "s/.tar.[a-z0-9]{2,3}$//" <<< $archive)
$ echo $directory
binutils-2.27
```

Comment: Use singe quotes around scripts unless you have a specific NEED not to do so (e.g. to let the shell expand a variable), do escape RE metacharacters if you want them treated literally (e.g. `.`), and do quote your variables (`echo "$directory"`) unless you have specific NEED not to (e.g. globbing)

Answer (score 3):

The `sed` based solution would be:

```
directory=$(sed -E 's/\.tar\.[a-z0-9]{2,3}$//' <<< $archive)
```

however, with some assumptions, you can use `bash` features only:

```
directory=${archive%.tar.*}
```